# Calculate math function depend on N value

Tags: java, design, c#, algorithms, optimization

I have method with the following prototype :

```
R[] = method(k,n)
```

which :

```
n = ordinal value 0 <n <10^9
k = math function depend on n value : i.e n^6
R = array of computed values
```

For example :

### n = 10^8

### k = n ^2

so then :

- n [index]= 1,2,3,...,10^8
- R [index]= 1,4,9,..,..

I dont want to do the common solution : iterate and solve each element and aggregate the result because of bad performance.
I am looking for solution that :

1. is optimized solution
2. work for any math function (maybe genric)
3. well designed

Answer (score 2):

There *cannot* be a generic solution that efficiently works for all functions. The only generic solution is to calculate the target function separately for each input combination. To get more efficient, you'd have to do one of the following:

- Exploit common sub-structures of the problem and avoid recomputing them multiple times. Ideally, this would lead to a dynamic programming solution. Recursive functions can be sped up with memoization, though this incurs extra space overhead.
- Make certain assumptions about the problem and approximate it, for example by interpolating values. This can work quite well if the target function has type ℝ<sup>n</sup> → ℝ<sup>m</sup> (operates on reals) *and* is differentiable *and* is not multimodal.